# How to (open/make) new window in Kivy-Python

Tags: python, oop, kivy

### how to make or open new window in Python-Kivy for pc something like repytly created window or redirect for new window

### Task:with press any bttn probably make new window to completely perform script for button

this example of primordail code

```
import sqlite3 as sq
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

with sq.connect("WordBase.db") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()



class MyApp(App):
    def inw(self, instance):
      lbl=BoxLayout()
      lbl.add_widget(Button(text='bttn 1'))
      return lbl


    def quiz(self,instance):
        print('QUIZ')

    def Setting(self,instance):
        print('Setting')

    def find(self,insance):
        print('FIND')



    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        bl.add_widget(Label(text='Wellcome',size_hint=(1,.4)))

        gl = GridLayout(cols=2, size_hint=(1, .6), padding=[20, 0, 20, 20], spacing=20)
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='Input New Word', font_size=25,background_normal='',background_color=[.33,.41,.45,1],  on_press=self.inw))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='QUIZ',           font_size=25,background_normal='',background_color=[.38,.91,.44,.5], on_press=self.quiz))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='Setting',        font_size=25,background_normal='',background_color=[.33,.41,.45,1],  on_press=self.Setting))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='FIND',           font_size=25,background_normal='',background_color=[.70,.39,.92,.4], on_press=self.find))

        bl.add_widget(gl)
        return bl


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you want to open an independent window by pressing a button?

Comment: @Neizvestnyj , yes  i need tree of func , like new tab in browser, but i don`t know how make it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess` for this

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

import subprocess
import sys
from threading import Thread

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: "Open new window"
        on_release: app.open_window()
"""


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    @staticmethod
    def open_window():
        Thread(target=lambda *largs: subprocess.run([sys.executable, "new_window.py"])).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

### new_window.py

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
Screen:
    Label:
        text: 'An additional window opened'
"""


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestApp().run()
```